# Get each index values separately from a Arraylist<Hashmap>

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap

I have a `private ArrayList<HashMap> list` and it is used to inflate a ListView so it has a few rows with two columns. Whenever I use `list.get(0)`, I get `{first=Charles, id=e46e650c-4d3e-4ac2-a45f-715bf31e05d7, second=Edwin}`.

I am having a hard time understanding the functions of `private ArrayList<HashMap> list` because I dont understand if its a ArrayList or a Hashmap.

How can I get the `first` value only then the `second` value only from the `ArrayList<Hashmap>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list contains hashmaps, which means if you access the first element, you will get a map:

```
Map<String, String> map = list.get(0);
String first = map.get("first");
String second = map.get("second");
```